# Is there a method for psychologically-sustainable minimalism?

Tags: reduce

Minimalism (aka [Simple Living](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_living)) is a great way to live an ecologically-sustainable life, but is there a way to make it sustainable from a pysochological standpoint as well? That is, how does one reduces one's feeling of deprivation while reducing one's material possessions?

Comment: I found that buying less stuff and cleaning up my house and getting rid of things I hardly ever use, gives a feeling of lightheartedness. It not only cleans up your home, somehow it also clears your head.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if it'll work for everyone, but my solution - and indeed, the way I arrived at living a (somewhat and in some respects) minimalist lifestyle - is to not think of things as deprivations, but as advantages.  So my not owning a TV is not depriving me of TV viewing, it's giving me lots of free time to do other (IMHO more interesting) things; not flying commercial is not deprivation of travel, but frees me from TSA indignities & seating discomfort; driving a small car gives me agility rather than depriving me of comfort & status; biking instead of driving gives me healthy exercise & recreation...

Comment: This has worked for me as well. It was minor, everyday eliminations and their slow refinement of my interests and requirements that eventually formed an all-encompassing attitude.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the key lies in refining the few things that you decide to keep.

Such an approach is described at [less.best](http://less.best).